# Kubernetes service with external name curl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Well, I created kubernetes-service.yaml file, now i suppose, that on the port 8081 my backend service will be exposed under the domain of my.backend.com. I would like to check whether its accessible, however I have it available only within a cluster. How do I do that? I dont want to expose service externally, I just want to make curl my.backend.com inside a cluster to check results. Is there any workaround of that?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
  labels:
    app: backend
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8080
  externalName: my.backend.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service itself is only exposed within the cluster, however, the FQDN my.backend.com is not handled or controlled by the cluster. This is likely a publicly accessible URL so you can curl from anywhere. You'll have to configure your domain in a way that restricts who can access it.

The service type externalName is external to the cluster and really only allows for a CNAME redirect from within your cluster to an external path. I'm sure what you are trying to do, but it's not a change you make at the cluster level.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when I have frontend and backend and I have for example exposed /project as a GET on backend and on frontend I will make requests to http://my.backend.com/project it should work as expected right?

Comment: my.backend.com/project will work as long as you have that working where ever it is (outside the cluster). the externalName service just allows myservice.default.svc.cluster.local to resolve to my.backend.com. It's basically a CNAME

Comment: Well, I was looking for kubectl exec -it POD_NAME COMMAND, however Your answer helped me to find it, thanks :)